# Writing data to a netCDF file with R

Tags: r, netcdf

I am trying to use the data on my own .csv file to create a netCDF file using the R package "ncdf4".
My dataset is composed by 3 columns: longitude, latitude and temperature and it has 2592 rows. 
I have been following the suggestions in the package to add the dimension and the variables to the netCDF file. Everything is fin until I want to write the temperature data on my file. 
I got this error:

```
Error in ncvar_put(nc = ncnew, varid = var_temp, data, start = c(1, 1,  : 
  ncvar_put: error: you asked to write 65160 values, but the passed data 
  array only has 2592 entries!
```

What's wrong?

```
library(ncdf)
library(ncdf4)

TimeTable<-read.csv("time.csv",header=T,sep=",")
filename="time.nc"

xvals<-1:360
yvals<--90:90
nx<-length(xvals)
ny<-length(yvals)
lon1<-ncdim_def("longitude","degrees_east",xvals)
lat2<-ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_north",yvals )

time<-ncdim_def("Time","months", 1:12, unlim=T )
mv <- -999 # missing value to use
var_temp<- ncvar_def("temperature", "celsius", list(lon1, lat2, time),longname="CRU_Global_1961-1990_Mean_Monthly_Surface_Temperature_Climatology",mv) 


ncnew<-nc_create(filename,list(var_temp))

print(paste("The file has",ncnew$nvars,"variables"))# 
print(paste("The file has",ncnew$ndim,"dimensions"))# 

data<-array(TimeTable$tem_1)
ncvar_put( nc=ncnew, varid=var_temp,data,start=c(1,1,1),count=c(nx,ny,1))
```

Could you please suggest me something?
Many thanks

Comment: The length of `xvals <- 1:360` is 360 and the length of `yvals <- -90:90` is 181. Thus, 360*181 = 65160 grid points. If "temperature" is not a regular grid, you need to write a station NetCDF. If "temperature" is a regular grid, you need to provide the exact coordinates in lon/x and lat/y, i.e. the correct ranges and the correct resolution.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal, but do you mean by a station NetCDF?I've checked my dataset and my latitude and longitude have those ranges: xvals <- as.array(seq(-177.5, 177.5, 0.5)), yvals <- as.array(seq(-87.5, 87.5, 5)). My temperature is not a regular grid...Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you have inside "temperature"? Synoptic stations or grid points from model/reanalysis/interpolation?

Comment: lon lat tem_1
-177.5 87.5 -30.1
-172.5 87.5 -30.1
-167.5 87.5 -30.5
-162.5 87.5 -30.5
-157.5 87.5 -30.3
-152.5 87.5 -30.2
this is how my dataset looks like

Comment: So you have to use this: `xvals <- seq(-177.5, 177.5, 5); yvals <- seq(-87.5, 87.5, 5)`, i.e. 72 longitudes and 36 latitudes (72*36=2592).

Comment: You were close to the solution with your above comment.

Comment: the problem now is that the file is empty. when I print the netcdf created I can see that the variable that should contain the value has missing value.  
     1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        float temperature[longitude,latitude,Time]   
            units: celsius
            _FillValue: -999
            long_name: Monthly_Surface_Temperature_Climatology

Answer (score 7):

```
library(ncdf4)

filename="time.nc"

xvals <- seq(-177.5, 177.5, 5)
yvals <- seq(-87.5, 87.5, 5) 
nx <- length(xvals)
ny <- length(yvals)
lon1 <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees_east", xvals)
lat2 <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_north", yvals)

time <- ncdim_def("Time","months", 1:12, unlim=TRUE)
mv <- -999 #missing value to use
var_temp <- ncvar_def("temperature", "celsius", list(lon1, lat2, time), longname="CRU_Global_1961-1990_Mean_Monthly_Surface_Temperature_Climatology", mv) 

ncnew <- nc_create(filename, list(var_temp))

print(paste("The file has", ncnew$nvars,"variables"))
#[1] "The file has 1 variables"
print(paste("The file has", ncnew$ndim,"dimensions"))
#[1] "The file has 3 dimensions"

# Some fake dataset based on latitude, to check whether the data are
# written in the correct order
data <- rep(yvals, each=nx)

# Add random -999 value to check whether missing values are correctly
# written
data[sample(1:(nx*ny), 100, replace = FALSE)] <- -999
ncvar_put(ncnew, var_temp, data, start=c(1,1,1), count=c(nx,ny,1))

# Don't forget to close the file
nc_close(ncnew)

# Verification
library(rasterVis)
out <- raster("time.nc")
levelplot(out, margin=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have another problem.My csv has Lat, Lon,Temperature. xvals <- seq(-180.0,179.91669, 0.0832825) yvals <- seq(-80,90, 0.0832825) 
data <- GlobT[,3]. The file has 1 variable Temperature [lon,lat,depth,time] and 4 dimensions(lon,lat,depth,time). I have followed the approach of the above example but my file does not look fine. The variable is defined as : var_temperature<-ncvar_def("temperature","K",list(xdim,ydim,Depth,Time), longname="Temperature",prec="double",mv) with  mv<- -999 and ncvar_put(ncnew,var_temperature,data,start=c(1,1,1,1),count=c(nx,ny,1,1)). Why my netcdf looks empty?

Comment: Error in ncvar_put(ncnew, var_temperature, data, start = c(1, 1, 1, 1),  : 
  ncvar_put: error: you asked to write 8825524 values, but the passed data array only has 6147539 entries!

Comment: it is very strange since, it looks like cannot really take the data I want to use to fill my temperature value.

Comment: Could you please give me some suggestions?my variable temperature is still empty. It does not contain any of the value in the 3rd column of my .csv file data<-Glob[,3]

Comment: Did you check the lengths of `xvals` and `yvals`? They respectively are 4322 and 2042, i.e. 8825524 grid points. What are the dimensions of GlobT? But the most important is: do you have all the grid points on your csv file or only temperatures above the land? For the latter, your approach is completely wrong.

Comment: dim(GlobT) is [1] 6147539       3. Yes the lengths of xvals and yvals are fine. The csv file reports all values of seawater temperature except the NA. I have extracted the csv from a netcdf turning the variable in a dataframe (lat lon temperature) and then writing as a csv

Comment: So you don't have a complete grid, but only ocean grid points. If you want to create a NetCDF file, you need to create the missing grid points in "GlobT", then you can use `xvals` and `yvals`.

Comment: so do you think is better not to remove the missing values when creating the csv?and thus trying in this way to create the .nc file?

Comment: I don't know/understand what you are trying to do by extracting values from a NetCDF, writing a csv file with this, then reading the csv file to write a NetCDF file...

Comment: I know seems strange, but I have a lot of .csv file that I want to turn into NetCDF. and i took one as reference to compare the results