# R -How to create a time series netcdf file

Tags: r, netcdf

I'm trying to create a .nc file that has monthly data from 1981-2014. But I'm obtaining the data from .dat files, each file represents one month of one year.

From this tutorial http://geog.uoregon.edu/GeogR/topics/netcdf-to-raster.html I'm using this code:

```
library(ncdf4)

nlon <- 360
nlat<- 180

dlon <- 360.0/nlon
dlat <- 180.0/nlat

lon <- seq(-180.0+(dlon), +180.0,by=dlon) 
lat <- seq(-90.0+(dlat),+90.0,by=dlat)

#This is how I add one data set

DD <- as.matrix(read.table("~/1981_01_NAM.dat", header=FALSE))
datos1 <- t(matrix(t(DD),ncol=360,nrow=180, byrow=TRUE))


londim <- ncdim_def("lon", "degrees_east", as.double(lon))
latdim <- ncdim_def("lat", "degrees_north", as.double(lat))

varname ="humedad"
units = "z-scores"
dlname <- "test-variable -- original"
fillvalue <- 1e20
tmp.def <- ncvar_def(varname, units, list(londim, latdim), fillvalue, dlname, prec = "single")


ncfname <- "test-humedad.nc"
ncout <- nc_create(ncfname, list(tmp.def), force_v4 = TRUE)

ncvar_put(ncout, tmp.def, datos1)

ncatt_put(ncout, "lon","axis","X")
ncatt_put(ncout, "lat","axis","Y")


title <- "Prueba Humedad"
ncatt_put(ncout, 0, "title", title)

nc_close(ncout)
```

So how con I asign each .dat file to a month in the .nc file so I can obtain the complete time series?

Comment: I think you need to read and combine all `.dat` files first

Comment: Some links might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949971/writing-data-to-a-netcdf-file-with-r

Comment: http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html#convert-a-full-r-data-frame-to-an-array

Comment: The `ncvar_put` function permits you to append data to an NCDF file that already exists. Perhaps you could put your single-file code into a function and loop on a vector of 'dat' file names after you've created the first month's file.